# HTTP 500 is always code issue?

Tags: http

I want to know if HTTP 500 error can ever happen due to error in core server? Or is HTTP 500 ALWAYS  script (PHP) issue?

```
This page isn’t working
xxx.xxxxx.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Thanks

Comment: can anyone pls answer instead of downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 was *designed* to represent server errors. It's in the name: Internal Server Error.

Application errors can also result in HTTP 500, and are probably more common, but yes, server errors are HTTP 500 just as well because that's what it originally means, and anyone who tells you otherwise (i.e. that server errors are *not* HTTP 500) is wrong.